# Distribution of a max of transforms of an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

> The random variable $X$ has an exponential distribution function given by density:
> $$
> f_X(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> e^{-x}, & x\ge 0,\\
> 0,   & x<0.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Find the distribution and density function of the random variable $Y=\max\left\{X^2,2-X\right\}$.

I honestly just don't know how to start here.

1. Why should we be able to calculate this if we don't know what exactly X is?
2. What is X^2 and 2-X ? I don't understand that
3. And even knowing all of this, how should we be able to find the distribution and density function of Y?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you don't know what $X$ is? $Y$ is a function of $X$ and distribution of $X$ is given (should be $e^{-x}$).

Comment: But X is a random variable, thus it should be something like X = {1, 2, 3} for example. It's supposed to be a set, thus something like X^2 doesnt really make sense

Comment: How can a random variable be a set? It is a mapping from your sample space to the set of real numbers. Here $X$ is continuous, so it does not take some isolated values.

Comment: Ok but how should we be able to calculate the density and distribution function for Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graphic approach

Note: as already note in a comment, $f(x)=e^{-x}\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(x)$

First of all note that $X\sim Exp(1)$ and so

- $\mathbb{P}[X \leq x]=F_X(x)=1-e^{-x}$
- $\mathbb{P}[X > x]=S_X(x)=e^{-x}$

Let's have a look at the graph

[image]

Now it is clear which is the transformation function and which is Y domain:

$y \in [1;+\infty)$

To derive $ CDF_Y$ let's use the definition

$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[2-y \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}]=S_X(2-y)-S_X(\sqrt{y})=e^{y-2}-e^{-\sqrt{y}}$

This, obviously when $y \in[1;2)$

For the other interval, same but more simply story

$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X^2\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq \sqrt{y}]=F_X(\sqrt{y})=1-e^{-\sqrt{y}}$

Summarizing...

$F_Y(y)=[e^{y-2}-e^{-\sqrt{y}}]\mathbb{1}_{[1;2)}(y)+[1-e^{-\sqrt{y}}]\mathbb{1}_{[2;+\infty)}(y)$

derive and you get your density

***Further Basic explanation answering to the latest comment of the OP***

Your density is a known Law: a Negative Exponential with $\theta=1$. It is easy to verify that because the Exp neg density is the following

$f(x,\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$

$x \geq 0$ and zero elsewhere. So we immediately know which are the CDF and the survival function (anyway they can be easily calculated with the integral)

- YOUR CDF

$F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}[X \leq x]=1-e^{-x}$

- YOUR SURVIVAL FUNCTION

$S_X(x)=\mathbb{P}[X > x]=1-F_X(x)=e^{-x}$

Now for the sake of simplicity let's suppose we are looking at the following transformation:

$Y=X^2$

So, by definition, we have

$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X^2\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X \leq \sqrt{y}]=$

(by definition)

$=F_X(\sqrt{y})=1-e^{\sqrt{y}}$

If you have understood this procedure, you can apply it to your exercise that is a little bit more complex by the fact that the transformation function is

$Y=Max[2-X;X^2]$

but with the help of the grafh I showed you should be able to understand the solution. If not, I suggest you to challenge with easier exercise to become familiar with the procedure.
Also the Fundamental Tranformation Theorem could help but the procedure I showed you is very useful to understand the issue you are facing.

2nd Edit:

$\mathbb{P}[2-y < X < \sqrt{y}]=F_X(1)-F_X(2-y)+F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(1)=$

$=F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(2-y)=1-S_X(\sqrt{y})-[1-S_X(2-y)]=$

$=S_X(2-y)-S_X(\sqrt{y})$

Comment: What does ∼(1) mean and from where do we know this? Also, why exactly $F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[2-y \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}]=S_X(2-y)-S_X(\sqrt{y})=e^{y-2}-e^{-\sqrt{y}}$ and $F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X^2\leq y]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq \sqrt{y}]=F_X(\sqrt{y})=1-e^{-\sqrt{y}}$?

Comment: @Student   1) the density of exp neg rv is $f(x)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$. Your rv is exp neg wih $\theta=1$. 2) and 3) should be self evident by inverting the transformation functions...see graph (I did it just for your help)

Comment: What is "rv" if i may ask?

Comment: ℙ[≤]=()=1−^(−) ℙ[>]=()=^(−) I still don't get why this should be the case here?

Comment: @Student : rv = random variable. I edited my answer with a lot of basic information. I hope this helps. On the countrary, post some easier examples just to become familiar with the procedure and we will solve them together...

Comment: I would like to know easier examples lol but they ain't giving us none

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your edit!! But I still don't understand from where $$F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[2-y \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}]=S_X(2-y)-S_X(\sqrt{y})=e^{y-2}-e^{-\sqrt{y}}$$ is comming from. For me, the second SX should be FX as X is smaller than sqrt(y)

Comment: @Student : Read the 2nd EDIT...

Comment: $F_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}[Y \leq y]=\mathbb{P}[2-y \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}]$ - Why $\mathbb{P}[2-y \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}]$? Why not $1 - \mathbb{P}[X \leq 2-y]$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{split}
F_Y(y)
 &= \mathbb{P}[Y \le y] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[\max\{X^2,2-X\} \le y] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[X^2 \le y,2-X \le y] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[|X| \le \sqrt{y},X \ge 2+y] \\
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish and express $F_Y(y)$ in terms of $F_X(\cdot)$ and $f_X(\cdot)$?

Comment: I don't know, I can't find the link here.